# how to pack into frame class python tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Here I pack a Label into a frame class but it doesn't pack inside the frame it packs in the other side the window class. Here is a screenshot of the results in a [image: screenshot]. Code:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def AddImage(path, size):
        rawimage = Image.open(path)
        rawimage = rawimage.resize(size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        cleanimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rawimage)
        print("add image run")
        return cleanimage


class LeftFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container,bg="red",width=400,height=600)
        self.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        self.test = Window.AddImage(r"assets\images\add-word.png",size=(20,20))
        self.testLabel = tk.Label(image = self.test)
        self.testLabel.pack()


        
        
    
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = Window()
    frame = LeftFrame(win)
    win.geometry("800x600")
    win.resizable(0, 0)
    win.configure(bg="#58e0dc")
    win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have to explicitly set the parent of all widgets, if you don't want them to be direct children of the root window - this is done via the first positional parameter to all widget constructors.  The mere fact that `self.testLabel` is being created inside the `LeftFrame` class does not make it a child of the Frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `self` as the first argument of your `testLabel`.  This sets the parent for the label so it knows where to pack itself.

```
   def widgets(self):
        self.test = Window.AddImage(r"assets\images\add-word.png",size=(20,20))
        self.testLabel = tk.Label(self, image = self.test)
        # self.pack_propagate(0)  <-optional
        self.testLabel.pack()
```

Comment: also have to use pack propgate

Comment: @GCIreland  good tip... I added it to the example

Comment: I think it's bad advice to suggest turning geometry propagation off. It's rarely necessary.